# JTextField's getText() to printable variable

Tags: java, variables, user-interface, jframe, jtextfield

I've just taken up playing with GUIs, and I'm experimenting with getting text input from the user, and assigning it to a variable for later use.

Easy, I thought. Wrong, I was.

I wanted my frame to look something like:

```
public class firstFrame extends JFrame {

JTextField f1 = new JTextField();
String text;

public firstFrame(String title) {
    super(title);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Container c = getContentPane();

    c.add(f1);

    text = f1.getText();

    System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Where the variable `text` would get whatever text the user typed in, then print it out to the console. Simple.

I've got a feeling I'm missing something pretty fundamental here, and would appreciate it if anyone could fill me in on what that something is.

Comment: The textfield wont have any text in it until the user types. When the user types in it, you'd want to call `text = f1.getText();` Add a keylistener to the textfield and when an event is captured, save the text.

Comment: What you wanna learn about is Eventhandlers, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/ which listens to the components in your program and tells you when something happens, i.e. user input.

Comment: @Martin I'll read up on that. Thanks Martin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getText()` *only* get the text that is in the `JTextArea` at the time it is called.

You are calling it in the constructor. So when you instantiate `new firstFrame`, there is no initiital text.

One thing to keep in mind is that GUIs are event driven, meaning you need an event handler to capture and process events.

One option is to add an `ActionListener` to the `JTextField` so when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering text, the text will print.

```
f1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String text = f1.getText();
        System.out.println(text);
    }
});
```

See more at how to [Create GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [Writing Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

The variable won't be updated until an event occurs on the component. For this a `DocumentListener` or `ActionListener` can be used

```
f1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String text = f1.getText();
        ...
    }
});
```